# ASP web service connection to SSAS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, ssas

I have a ASP web service. I'm using  IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 R2. When I try to connect to SSAS, I get the following error.

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException: Either the user, NT AUTHORITY\IUSR, does not have access to the Adventure Works DW 2008R2 database, or the database does not exist.

Can someone fix it?

This is how I connect to SSAS.

```
Server con = new Server();
con.Connect("Datasource=localhost; Initial Catalog=Adventure Works DW 2008R2;");
XmlaResultCollection result = con.Execute(xmla);
```

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either give IUSR permissions to access SSAS, or run your application's application pool identity as a windows account, then give that account permissions to access SSAS. Look into SSAS roles, as ideally you don't want to give IIS server-level permissions on SSAS.